# c# HTMLElement get specific child

Tags: c#, html, dom

let's say I have HTML stored in HTMLElement object. It's outerHTML property looks like this.

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         a
      </td>
      <td>
         b
      </td>
      <td>
         c
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

How do I get the third `<td>` with the innerHTML `"c"`?
I have no problem in switching the data to some other object, I just want to be able to do this easily? I was thinking about parsing it as XML and then using XPath, but I had no luck with that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to load the document and then you can apply an XPath on it in order to retrieve the node(s) you are interested in.
The expression in your case would be:

```
//table/tr/td[position()=2]
```

If you have more rows, then it will return all td elements with position 2 (zero based index) from each row.